# Let $K,L$ over $Q$ be field extension of prime degrees. Prove if $[KL:Q]<[K:Q][L:Q]$, then the Galois closure of $K/Q$ is the Galois closure of $L/Q$.

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

Let $K$ and $L$ over $Q$ be field extension of prime degrees. Prove that if $[KL:Q]<[K:Q][L:Q]$, then the Galois closure of $K/Q$ equals to the Galois closure of $L/Q$.

I know the two extensions must be simple extensions, and the two degrees are equal. But I cannot figure out the rest.

Comment: I am intrigued by this question. It is, indeed, easy to show that the two primes are equal. It is easy to find examples of such pairs of fields $K,L$ for all primes $p$. And in all the examples I have thought of $K$ and $L$ are conjugates implying the claim. Yet I don't see why they would need to always be conjugates.

Comment: [Somewhat related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/434995/11619).

Comment: How did you run into this question?

Comment: The main claim follows from [Derek Holt's answer to my related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4877153/11619).